# Reading zipped gpkg files (i.e. `*.gpkg.zip`) with Python

Tags: python, geopandas, geopackage

I have many large `gpkg.zip` files that I would like to read directly into Python (to then upload to BigQuery). I can unzip each, read with `geopandas`, then upload -- however, since unzipping triples the space the file takes up, it starts to really clog up my computer's relatively small hard drive.

Is there a way to read a compressed file in directly?

Comment: Looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574407/python-open-a-compressed-sqlite-database and seems not possible. Why don't you do sequentially, unzip file1, read file1, upload file1 content and delete unzipped file? Storage required on your computer = same size as all your zip + 3 times the size or your current zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GDAL `/vsizip` system.

I have this geopackage with one layer:

```
$ ogrinfo ottawa.gpkg 
INFO: Open of `ottawa.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
1: ottawa (Multi Polygon)
```

And I can create a zip file containing just it:

```
$ zip ottawa.gpkg.zip ottawa.gpkg 
  adding: ottawa.gpkg (deflated 38%)
```

And its nice and smaller than the source:

```
$ ls -sh ottawa.gpkg*
872K ottawa.gpkg  544K ottawa.gpkg.zip
```

Then I can access that file with `/vsizip` with the zip file name and the name of the file in the zip file:

```
$ ogrinfo /vsizip/ottawa.gpkg.zip/ottawa.gpkg 
INFO: Open of `/vsizip/ottawa.gpkg.zip/ottawa.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
1: ottawa (Multi Polygon)
```

The downside is this will be slower.